# What does "Directory Index forbidden by rule" mean?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, indexing, root, directoryindex

What could the following line mean?

```
[Mon Feb 21 20:52:13 2011] [error] [client 66.249.71.150] 
 Directory index forbidden by rule: /var/www/vhosts/website.com/httpdocs/
```

I have no index.php in the root, since my index is home.php, website root file is defined by .htaccess rules:

My **.htaccess** file looks like this:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php /index.php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^website.com$
RewriteRule ^$ en/home [R=301,L]
...
```

Thanks very much!

## update1:

I dont have access to the virtual host config files, im on shared hosting , so only .htacces in my /httpdocs/  thats all I have. What should I do? Should I jus disable DirectoryIndex (I dont use that anyways and the site works fine!) How can I check wether I have directory index or not?

## update2:

- when testing in browser, all seem to work fine, fast and nicely!
- in log however, i see this:

> [Sun Feb 27 02:18:56 2011] [error]
> [client 66.249.71.81] File does not
> exist:
> /var/www/vhosts/website.org/httpdocs/index

Unlike the first error at the top of this page, this seems a regular 404 (my 404 error document is my home page, so error pages show the home)

When I type in 'website.org' the htaccess rule does goed job in redirecting to the default page  website.org/en/home   and when I type 'websie.org/index' it redirects to website.org/en/home   so it all seems to work fine but i dons know what the two error means **"Directory index forbidden by rule..."**

Clues? Thanks!

Comment: I just updated my answer again. That <Directory /> bit is possible to place inside of the .htaccess file as well. I sort of jumped to the conclusion that you were having an error I sometimes encounter. Can you give a little bit more background to the problem? Is this a sub-directory that you're trying to serve from, or the main dir? Have you successfully hosted things on this server before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT 2:** Ok... I think I just completely misread this question at first. You say you don't have an `index.php` file in the directory? If so, `DirectoryIndex index.php /index.php` doesn't look correct. Maybe you should try changing that to:

```
DirectoryIndex home.php
```

Am I understanding the issue correctly? You're trying to display the default page for the directory, correct?

---

By default, some http.conf setups have the following rule:

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>
```

Whenever I set up a vhost, I often change this rule to look more like this:

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

The important parts in your case are the last two pieces `Order` and `Allow`.

**EDIT 1:** Actually, after looking into this error a bit more, it's possible that this is even a permissions issue. Can you double-check that Apache has read access to the directory you're trying to access?

Comment: Hi Gavin, thanks very much for thinking with me. Okey lets see, ive updated some more specific things in my question... curious what you make out of that.

Answer (score 1):

Check your  entries and make sure that your site's virtual host DocumentRoot is listed there, otherwise apache won't be able to get at it.